# lightweight framework for automatic IIS deployment

Tags: c#, windows, iis, deployment, fabric

Some background:

- I'm a Java server developer and works mostly for Linux server
- I use python as major scripting language for all trivial tasks, as well as deployment
- Now I'm going to move to a project using C# on Windows.

What's feature I like for fabric:

- fabric is lightweight, and easy for small team to learn
- python can do a lot of things than some deployment framework. For example, we manage hundreds of machines via a internal management portal, a lot of specified configurations and functionalities. We implemented the portal using Java and some fancy web framework. I use python to access the rest API from the server and retrieve server address/port and other information for deployment. The most convenient way to get it done is using a real programming language.
- with fabric, I can run any command on remote server. With this I can easily have workarounds for some unusual cases.
- again, python is really good to do customization work for servers, e.g. build an init.d script from template.

What I have checked for windows:

- Windows Deployment Kit
- Ansible
- Chef
- (The list above may cost me too much to learn to get the right choice. I didn't dig into them.)

I also think about installing a ssh server software on windows. But I'm looking for a Windows way for Windows deployment.

The question is:
Is there an easy to learn and lightweight script framework for windows server deployment? my goal is to automatic everything for deployment to multiple IIS instances, and also, handle some daily/weekly ops tasks.

Comment: This question is in the wrong spot. It needs to move to superuser.com.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I may need to refine the question. It's a programming question though.

Answer (score -1):

My Final solution that works pretty well:

- install cygwin on windows server
- install sshd as service
- use python fabric to handle deployment

  - run commands on server using fabric
  - sync files using rsync
- steps of uploading files

  - upload a random password file to server
  - start rsync daemon on remote server
  - upload file with modification check and compression using rsync
  - stop rsync daemon on remote server
  - server provision